# issue populating an array swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift

Trying to populate a ViewControler with an array, but getting the Array does not have a member name.  However, I have this same array set up several times with no issues, but they are all inside a tableView, and this is a ViewController.

Controller with the error:

```
class LocationViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate, LocationDelegate
{

var diveSiteArray: Array<DiveSiteSimpleModel> = [DiveSiteSimpleModel]()

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        self.diveSiteArray = AppDelegate.getDLDatabase().getDiveSitesSimple()
        loadSitesArray()

        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: siteLatitude,longitude: siteLongitude)
        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.15, 0.15)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = location
        annotation.title = diveSiteLabel
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)

    }

}
 func loadSitesArray () {

    self.diveSiteLabel = diveSiteArray.name  // here I get the error "Array< DiveSiteSimpleModel > does not have a member name
    siteLongitude = diveSiteArray.longitude  // here I get the error "Array< DiveSiteSimpleModel > does not have a member longitude
    siteLatitude = diveSiteArray.latitude   // here I get the error "Array< DiveSiteSimpleModel > does not have a member latitude
}
```

The DiveSiteSimpleModel is below:

```
struct DiveSiteSimpleModel
{
    var id: Int                     = -1
    var name: String                = ""
    var latitude: Double            = 0.0
    var longitude: Double           = 0.0
    var diveSiteImage: String       = ""

}
```

The DLDatabase is as follows:

```
func getDiveSitesSimple(_ query: String) -> Array<DiveSiteSimpleModel>
{
    var sites: Array<DiveSiteSimpleModel> = [DiveSiteSimpleModel]()

    if self.database == nil {
        return sites
    }

    var statement: OpaquePointer? = nil

    sqlite3_prepare_v2(self.database, query, -1, &statement, nil)
    while sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW
    {
        var site: DiveSiteSimpleModel =  DiveSiteSimpleModel()

        site.id                 = Int(sqlite3_column_int64(statement, 0))
        site.name               = String(cString: (sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)))
        site.latitude           = Double(sqlite3_column_double(statement, 2))
        site.longitude          = Double(sqlite3_column_double(statement, 3))
        site.diveSiteImage      = String(cString: (sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4)))

        sites.append(site)

    }

    sqlite3_finalize(statement)

    return sites
}
```

Lastly, the SQL is

```
static let SelectDiveSiteSimple         = "SELECT * FROM DiveSite"
```

Going crazy over this, any help would be huge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`diveSiteArray` is an array of `DiveSiteSimpleModel` structs. When you get the error you are treating `diveSiteArray` as an instance of `DiveSiteSimpleModel` not the array that it actually is. You need to reference one of the `DiveSiteSimpleModel` structs inside `diveSiteArray` like:

```
diveSiteLabel = diveSiteArray[0].name
```

To get the name element of the first struct in the array.

Answer (score 0):

In the following lines :

```
func loadSitesArray () {

    self.diveSiteLabel = diveSiteArray.name  // here I get the error "Array< DiveSiteSimpleModel > does not have a member name
    siteLongitude = diveSiteArray.longitude  // here I get the error "Array< DiveSiteSimpleModel > does not have a member longitude
    siteLatitude = diveSiteArray.latitude   // here I get the error "Array< DiveSiteSimpleModel > does not have a member latitude
}
```

The diveSiteArray does not have the these properties. Which is what the warning/error says. You need to extract each element from the array (in a for loop?) and then check the property of each DiveSiteSimpleModel.

Answer (score 0):

Your result is an array of `diveSiteArray`. So, you have to traverse through this array. Sample code:

```
for diveSite in diveSiteArray{
    print(diveSite.name)
    print(diveSite.longitude)
    print(diveSite.latitude)
}
```